# Identify this resource conversion game

Tags: identify-this-game

Here's what I can remember about this game:

- There are different resources in the form of different coloured (wooden?) cubes
- You can buy cards that give you the ability to convert the cubes, i.e. 1 red to 4 brown, or 1 brown and 3 grey to 1 yellow
- This conversion is shown vertically on the side of the card in this manner (I think) :

  - [red cube]
  - [red cube]
  - [grey cube]
  - [up/down arrow]
  - [yellow cube]
- Cards that are available to be bought have a bonus resource placed on them in order, which you gain when you buy that card, i.e. the first/left-most card gives you bonus 3 cubes if you buy it, the next gives you 2 cubes, etc.

I can't remember what the goal was supposed to be. Any help or questions to jog my memory of this game would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling various terms together, I found it:

[Century Spice Road](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/209685/century-spice-road)

Comment: Sorry I didn’t see this an hour ago; was just about to post the answer! Glad you found it.